# Get the height of product images within Magento

Tags: php, magento

Within Magento's media.phtml file you can get the image height for the first product image with:

```
<?php $imageWidth = $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->getOriginalWidth(); ?>
```

However this does not work for further product images (within the foreach loop):

```
<?php if (count($this->getGalleryImages()) > 1): ?>
<?php foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $_image): ?>
```

neither does..

```
<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'image', $_image->getFile())->getOriginalWidth(); ?>
```

Anyone have the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Catalog image helper is lacking support for those kind of operations. You will have to initialize your image model and get sizes from there. So:

```
<?php foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $_image): ?>
  <?php $image = new Varien_Image($_image->getPath()); ?>
  <?php echo $image->getOriginalWidth(); ?>
  <?php echo $image->getOriginalHeight(); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @Jernej, I ended up using the PHP getimagesize function (see my answer below). I'm not sure if there is any reason not to use either one.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Jernej's answer is:

```
$imagelink = $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'image', $_image->getFile());                        

list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($imagelink);

echo $width;
```

Comment: but this going to return a url as in http://www.example.com/ isn't it? and when you use getimagesize, it will make unnecessary http request to your site which can slow down the process significantly

Comment: getimagesize returns an array with 7 elements: http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php. One of the comments says 'getimagesize will download the entire image before it checks for the requested information. This is extremely slow on large images that are accessed remotely.'

Comment: I suggest to str_replace the domain part from your $imagelink to get path on your server before doing getimagesize, that way php will read the image locally and can save loading time. it makes big difference especially if you use it on several images in one page.